# How to use Workbook_BeforeClose from a custom module

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to prompt the user when he tries to close a workbook like this

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel as Boolean) 
 MsgBox "Changes has been detected. Do you want to export the data ?"
End Sub
```

I know that this code need to be placed in ThisWorkbook module. 
Is there a way to do that from my custom module ? I need to add this functionality to multiple workbooks used by my client as a part of up-gradation, which is usually done by replacing old modules with new modules.

Comment: At least you have to call your function/sub in`ThisWorkbook ` module. Then you can keep other codes in custome module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how you can Import the **ThisWorkbook Module**. I wrote some Code for that a long Time ago.

So how does it work.

1. First you have to Export the **ThisWorkbook Module**. Right click on the Module and Export.
2. Save the **ThisWorkbook.cls** on the Server where you have your other Module's or send it with the Modules (Like how you do the Upgrade of the other Modules)
3. Open the **ThisWorkbook.cls** File with a Editor (Like Notepad++)
   And Delete The First Rows. They Look like This.

   **VERSION 1.0 CLASS**

   **BEGIN**

   **MultiUse = -1  'True**

   **END**
4. Execute the **UpdateThisDocument** Subrutine.

   The Only Question how have to answer yourself is how you will Execute The Code ^^ (I wrote en Extern Updater that Executed the Code)

   ```
   Sub UpdateThisDocument()
     Dim ModuleName As String
     ModuleName = "DieseArbeitsmappe"
     Dim aDoc As Workbook
     Set aDoc = ThisWorkbook
     Dim strPath As String
     'Put here the Path to the Folder where the cls File of This Workbook is.
     strPath = "C:\Users\z002mkvy\Desktop\"
     With aDoc          
        If ModuleExists(ModuleName) = True Then
          Call clsLoeschen
        End If
       '

       With ThisWorkbook.VBProject
         .VBComponents(ModuleName).CodeModule.AddFromFile _
           strPath & "\DieseArbeitsmappe.cls"
     Fehler:
         End With
     End With
     End Sub



   Private Function ModuleExists(ModuleName As String) _
     As Boolean
     On Error Resume Next
     ModuleExists = Len(ThisWorkbook.VBProject _
     .VBComponents(ModuleName).Name) <> 0
   End Function

   Private Sub clsLoeschen()
     Dim modcls
     Dim awcl As Integer
     On Error Resume Next
     Set modcls = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Item("DieseArbeitsmappe")
     awcl = modcls.CodeModule.CountOfLines
     modcls.CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, awcl
     Set modcls = Nothing
   End Sub
   ```

I hope This can Help you

Comment: Your code seems to come from Word as it's using ActiveDocument?  Won't work in Excel as-is...  And "clsLoeschen" indiscriminately kills the first VBComponent in the project, and not the specific module being upgraded.

Comment: @CarlColijn Ops. Yeah you are right. Forget to Change that. The Code was Original from a Visio Project. But i Changed it. So now it works fine with Excel. Thansk for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application.VBE object and Workbook.VBProject to modify a file's VBA.  Note however that it requires that the Excel performing the upgrade has to have the setting "Trust access to the VBA project" toggled on (it can be found in the Trust center under the tab Macro settings).  When not needed anymore, it's an option best left off though for security reasons.